# Vector access with potentially undefined index

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a `Grid`, which is represented by two-dimensional `Vectors`.

Now I want to define a method which tests if the given `row` and `column` are part of the `Grid` and fulfill a certain condition (in this case if the number is `> 0`).

Ideally, I'd like to do the following:

```
g(row)(col) > 0
```

However, this results in exceptions if the indices are outside the `Vector`'s bounds.

What I came up with is this:

```
def isGt0(g: Grid, row: Int, col: Int) = {
  if(g.isDefinedAt(row) && g(row).isDefinedAt(col)) g(row)(col) > 0
  else false
}
```

Is there a better way to do that?

The full sample can be found [here](http://scalafiddle.net/console/c3992e9a68c5ae12bd18488bc579b30d).

Comment: You could start by removing the if/else, `g.isDefinedAt(row) && g(row).isDefinedAt(col) && g(row)(col) > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is more or less equivalent to what you have but (at least arguably) more idiomatic:

```
def isGt0(g: Grid, row: Int, col: Int) =
  g.lift(row).flatMap(_.lift(col)).fold(false)(_ > 0)
```

This works because `Vector[A]` is a partial function from `Int` to `A`. We can use the `.lift` method to make this a total function from `Int` to `Option[A]`, where we get `None` if we're out of bounds. We use `flatMap` to chain the two requests monadically, and `fold` to perform the check if there's a value and return `false` otherwise.

Neither of these versions is terribly efficient, though, and if you're doing this a lot and performance matters, you probably want plain old bounds checking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I have to admit I'm somewhat underwhelmed - I expected something significantly simpler. Guess I'm a bit spoiled by Scala...